# Empty result when using pandas GroupBy and sum?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum a column from a pandas dataframe and I get this weird output.
My code looks like this

```
DataFrame.groupby('column1').column2.sum()
```

instead of getting a sum of column2 I get this output:

```
Series([], Name: column2, dtype: int64)
```

Why am I getting this result?

Comment: Would you mind running `print(df.head())` and [edit]ing your question to include that output so people can debug and figure out what's happening?

Comment: is `column1` completely null?